# Android Studio Unable to execute DEX

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this weird error which keeps complaining about the dex files whenever i try to run the application in android studio. Does anyone knows what is it?

```
[2013-12-28 14:52:02 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-12-28 14:52:02 - TestApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is stating that it there are multiple copies of one of the v4 support library that you are using in your project. Go into the project structure -> modules and check in the target or the apk-libs folder if there are more than one copies. If there are more than one, exclude one of the library, do a clean and it should solve the problem

Comment: Hello, can not really understand you. Could u give me more detail? Or check the [same error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264223/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-in-android-studio) for me please?

Comment: Go into your lib folders of the projects you added and only keep the ones that are duplicate in the main project lib folder.