# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/ in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I can `integrate (add & work) with many libraries`.

But as for `ActionBarSherlock` library, I have so many problems with it.

**First Issue** is the popular issue `Multiple dex files define`,

I know The `duplicated android-support-v4.jar` causes it, but I can not solve this issue now :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':fitness:dexDebug'.

Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I followed the answer in [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989317/multiple-dex-files-define-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservice-accessibility). It used :

```
dependencies {
    compile('...') {
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

But I received **Second Issue** : `unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'exclude()'!` error.
Therefore I changed `build.gradle` of `main module` like this:

```
//configurations {
//    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
//}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services')
    compile files('/google-play-services/libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile (project(':actionbarsherlock')) {
        exclude(module: 'support-v4')
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}
```

`Solved` **Second Issue**, But still get **First Issue** `Multiple dex files define` error.

I read many topics, but can not solve **First Issue** now,

Please help me,

Thanks,

*p/s : I can sync with Gradle successully, but when run, it get above errors.*

*I used Android studio 0.5.5*

**EDIT**

`build.gradle` of `ActionBarSherlock`, it has only one `android-support-v4.jar`:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

`setting.gradle` like this :

```
include ':fitness', ':google-play-services',':actionbarsherlock'
```

@Garbriele : I updated new question, show `build.gradle of project` and `build.gradle of main module`
`build.gradle` of `project`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` of `main module` after edited :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' // Get following error in this line
}
```

I got this error in below :

[image]

Okay, thanks for @Garbriele comment, I already fixed this by using this :

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' // Get following error in this line
    }
```

**EDIT 2** When I put like this :

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Still get **First Issue** `Multiple dex files define` error.

What I want now is how to add `com.google.android.gms:play-services` library via `Maven` successfully,

Please help me,

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

After followed these steps :

- Put the library via Maven in `build.gradle` of main module : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`
- `Restart Android Studio`
- `Sync project with gradle`

No longer get this error again.

Comment: You could use compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' and compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23' to remove local libraries.

Comment: When I put `compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'` (it means download this library via maven). My gradle can not sync anymore `Gradle project sync failed ...`. U can help me fix this?

Comment: Did you add "repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}" to your build.gradle?

Comment: I'm finding it really hard to follow your question. Can you please edit it and highlight what you're currently having problems with? I'm confused by the parts where you were having trouble with something but then solved it.

Comment: @ScottBarta : Updated new question for u to know more detail. Still get main error as title of question. Please tell me the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So strange,

When I setup my dependencies like this :

```
repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

I still get the **First Issue** `Multiple dex files define` error.

But after following these steps:

- Put the library via Gradle in `build.gradle` of main module : `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`
- `Restart Android Studio`
- `Sync project with gradle`

I no longer get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had duplicate libraries in my libs directory:

```
$ ls -la libs/
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   5  wheel    170 25 Sep 22:09 .
drwxr-xr-x  10  wheel    340 25 Sep 22:07 ..
-rw-r--r--   1  wheel   3736 25 Sep 21:36 ApiComponent.jar
-rw-r--r--   1  wheel  28741 25 Sep 21:36 DependencyService.jar
-rw-r--r--   1  wheel   3736 25 Sep 22:09 classes.jar
```

Removing classes.jar worked for me.  I modified my DependencyService Project to produce DependencyService.jar instead of classes.jar causing the duplication.