# Local path doesnot exist

Tags: android, gradle

When I tried to run or debug, android studio 1.3.2 displays as "Local path doesn't exist" with device name also there is no apk file in the build folder Gradle-2.4 Gradle plugin-1.3

note:
i imported this project from eclipse

Edit: i fixed this problem..now the new one is"unable to find mainactivity in the dexpath class"

but classes1.dex and classes2.dex were generated

Comment: Try sync gradle (Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files). If that doesn't work, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=local+path+doesn't+exist&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-SearchBox&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7GGHP_enUS598&gws_rd=ssl). You'll see plenty of posts that tell you what to do. If that doesn't work, come back and tell us what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: i tried all those things from google page 1.invalidate caches 2.reimported 3.changed iml file

Comment: Are you sure? You've tried every single answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256177/android-studio-local-path-doesnt-exist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869611/android-studio-apk-install-error-local-path-doesnt-exist , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451049/android-studio-1-0-local-path-doesnt-exist ? And none of it works?

Comment: damn sure all those things were done except one ..ie gradle clean package through cmd

Answer (score 0):

include following in your app's gradle file and then clean->rebuild->run. :)

```
 dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
```

Comment: after doing this shows as "Error:Execution failed for task ':app_name:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/IntDef.class"

Comment: check your libs folder for duplicate entries. Since you were using eclipse before, I am assuming that you have downloaded support library jars and put them in your libs folder. Then, in Android studio, you again try to add the support libraries in your gradle file, which may cause **duplicate entry exception.** Please refer the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698579/multiple-support-v4-jars-causing-issues

Comment: could you please elaborate which one to do

Comment: Are you using any library projects in your current project?. Then, check whether your project's gradle file contains any duplicate entries, compared to the library's gradle file. If so, then remove the duplicate entry from your project's gradle file.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..now its running in nexus 5.1.1 but not in my redmi 1s 4.4.4 ,..it doesnot show any issue..do u need build.gradle file?

Comment: If my answer helps you to resolve your problem, then please upvote my answer :) .

What is the error you are getting, while running your application in redmi 1s 4.4.4?

Comment: while running the first activity ..it says ,"that activity is not present in multidex path" ..