# Multi dex eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-multidex

when i tried to run it shows error as below,can anyone tell me how to configure multidex in eclipse

Dx 
trouble writing output: Too many field references: 83958; 
max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.
References by package:
     2 android.graphics
   582 android.support.v7.appcompat
 83374

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Android multidex support library using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26530654/1048340)

> It looks like ADT's [ant-tasks project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/) is no longer maintained (it resides under 'legacy' folder).
>   So if you can't migrate to Gradle, you can edit the [DexExecTask](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/src/main/java/com/android/ant/DexExecTask.java) manually. You'll have of course to rebuild the project locally..
>
> **[Edit - 10/25/2014]** maven-android-plugin [does support multi-dex](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog). <s>However, it currently has a small issue: secondary dex files placed in wrong location. This [pull request](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/482) strives to fix that, so stay tuned!</s> (Fixed in 4.0.0)

I would suggest migrating to Android Studio.

Comment: migrating produces another problem,tell me the way to do in eclipse

Comment: Switch from ant to gradle. I'm sure there is a gradle plugin for Eclipse. What problems are you encountering while migrating?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551697/local-path-doesnot-exist/32558386?noredirect=1#comment53017404_32558386

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android services, just import the one you really need...In this way you can save lots of refences and stay under 65k avoiding the error.
Otherwise you need to use multidex-support

Download the library:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#multidex

And then add it to your project as described in the link.
Hope you can solve quickly your problem

Comment: just tell me how to use multidex in eclipse